# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/UploadedImages' is not allowed."

Tags: fine-uploader

Testing Fine-Uploader and get the following trying to upload images. It's on a testbox and I have rights to the folder. I am not running under IIS as most of these errors when searching google have to do with IIS. Any ideas.

I am using asp.net / c# and I am not using URL Rewriting.

Comment: What is `/UploadImages`?

Comment: I my directory to upload images in to from fine uploader. I just changed its default from /Uploads to what my folder is named where I am storing uploaded images

Comment: I meant what does it do? Is it WebApi or anything that filters by type of HTTP request?

Comment: http://fineuploader.com/ - It's just a file uploader plugin

Comment: _IINM_ they provide the client-side as well as server-side examples for setting up Azure/AWS (to handle/process the request). Are you saying you just have a folder?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/ASP.NET%20MVC%20C%23/UploadController.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the "/UploadImages" endpoint is not configured to accept POST requests (probably only GET requests). You'll need to update your server configuration appropriately so that POST requests are accepted.

Comment: you can't send http requests to a file system, you need a server

Comment: Running through visual studio (Visual Studio Development Server)

Comment: Then you do have a server. My answer applies.

Comment: Thanks Ray, how to you configure the Visual Studio Development Server settings?